# Use JSON attributes in a n-tuple QuerySet result in views.py in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I am newbie in django (and python) and I having trouble accessing a JSON attribute for a Django QuerySet result. The code generating the QuerySet is the following:

```
 species_list = Iris.objects.values("species").annotate(total=Count("species"))
 species = json.dumps(species_list,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

The JSON output from species looks like the following:

```
 [{"total": 50, "species": "setosa"}, {"total": 50, "species": "versicolor"}, {"total": 50, "species": "virginica"}]
```

What I want to do is to separate the "total" attribute values and "species" values to use for plotting purposes but inside the views.py for n3dv. i.e

```
xdata = species['species']
ydata = species['total']
```

But I get the error:

```
Django Version:  1.6.5
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value: string indices must be integers, not str
```

How do I properly extract this values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`species` is a list, which contains dictionaries. The list as a whole doesn't have a `species` key. You'd need to iterate through the list and access that key on each of the dictionaries inside it.